# Getting cleveref to mark all of "Lemma 1" as a hyperlink, not just "1"

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

I recently discovered the very nice `cleveref` package, and really like it. Works much better than `autoref` (from `hyperref`) for me. There is only one thing I don't like: If, for example, the `\cref` command inserts the text "Lemma 1", then only "1" is a clickable hyperlink. When using `\autoref`, the whole text is a hyperlink, which I really prefer (it's easier to hit the link this way).

Is there any way to get `cleveref` to work like this, too? Preferably one where I do not need to manually redefine the formatting for every reference type individually (i.e. for lemma, theorem, proposition, section, subsection, ...).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). As you can see, another site member took the liberty to format your post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Pass the `nameinlink` option to the `cleveref` package

```
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
```

A MWE follows, just for demonstration- see Section 6.2 of [the documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) for details

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Here is a section}\label{sec:mysection}
\begin{equation}
    f(x)=x^2+\sin(x)
\end{equation}

\cref{sec:mysection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aha! Seems the version of cleveref (version from 22/03/2011 as shipped with TeXLive 2011) is too old -- it doesn't support this option. Which is some relief, as I swear I searched the manual back and forth (I hate to ask questions and then find out they are answered in the manual). Time to upgrade the package, I guess. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fingolfin not sure I understand- this works fine for me. Perhaps an update is in order? (I'm on TeXlive 2011), and my version of `cleveref` is dated 2012/03/07

Comment: @Fingolfilm -- If you still have the 22/03/2011 version of `cleveref` (instead of the current version, 0.18.5, dated 07/03/2012), your system may not be set up in a way that runs `tlmgr` (TeX Live Manager) from time to time to obtain the latest versions of various LaTeX packages. The `nameinlink` option of the `cleveref` package was added last fall. Do consult your sys admin (maybe you?) and ask him/her to run `tlmgr update --self --all`. (Superuser privileges are required to run this command.)

Comment: @Mico great tip :) Note that one can change the permissions of `/usr/local/texlive` to be a normal user, in which case `tlmgr` does not need to be run as an admin. I'm not necessarily recommending it, just an FYI

Comment: @cmhughes -- In order to change the read-write permissions on `/usr/local/texlive` (and any lower directories) to something more permissive, wouldn't one already have to have superuser privileges to begin with (unless the system was set up in a nonstandard way from the start)?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes, I am superuser on my machine, but wasn't aware of the "tlmgr" command. I'll take a look at it, but I definitely wouldn't want to have it run automatically, as new package versions can introduce bugs or simply change behavior, which in turn could wreck what I am working on at a given time, which in turn would cause a horrible waste of time.

Comment: @Fingolfin -- I can understand your reluctance to run `tlmgr` entirely automatically. However, by not running `tlmgr` on a regular basis, you do incur the extra burden of having to be diligent about keeping an eye out for what's going on in the TeX world in terms of packages and updates -- including occasional significant improvements, as recently was the case with the `cleveref` package. Note that you can run `tlmgr update --list --all` to find out which packages would be updated (but without actually doing anything), and `tlmgr update <pkg>` to selectively update only one package at a time.

Comment: arxiv has this old version of cleveref. Is there a way to get `nameinlink` although having an old version?

Comment: @moose sorry, I've got absolutely no idea :)